# Limit transformation to top 1 row for each day in dataset

Tags: powerbi, transformation

**Background:**
Have a monitoring script that is run 3 times a day and outputs a .csv file to a SharePoint folder.  Each time the script is run, the new csv contains an update on the various processes run.  Currently able to get all of csv files back as a series of rows in the transformation.

**Question:**
Is there a way to limit the amount of rows for each day to just the Top 1 row so that the dashboard being created shows the most up-to-date information for each particular day. Would like to do this at the Transform stage so don't have to load any unnecessary data.

Eg. Example data in tranformation:

| Filename | Extension | Date created | *Keep in Transformation?* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file9 | .csv | 29/04/2021 07:52:41 | *KEEP* |
| file8 | .csv | 28/04/2021 16:52:14 | *KEEP* |
| file7 | .csv | 28/04/2021 11:52:20 | [redundant] |
| file6 | .csv | 28/04/2021 07:52:49 | [redundant] |
| file5 | .csv | 27:04/2021 16:51:41 | *KEEP* |
| file4 | .csv | 27/04/2021 11:52:21 | [redundant] |
| file3 | .csv | 27/04/2021 07:52:03 | [redundant] |
| file2 | .csv | 26/04/2021 16:52:43 | *KEEP* |
| file1 | .csv | 26/04/2021 11:52:20 | [redundant] |

Comment: Create a table from this table. Apply group by date and keep only max datetime. now join this both table, you will have only one row per day.

Answer (score 0):

Feels weird to answer my own question, but thought I would post, just in case someone has the same question...

The steps to get the latest row for each day are:

1. Ensure that the dataset is ordered by the **Date created** column in descending order.
2. Duplicate the **Date created** column to perform transformations on. It might create a new column called **Date created - Copy**.
3. Highlight the **Date created - Copy** column, and then select **Split Column by Delimiter**. As it's a Date/Time column, I split the column by the **Space** delimiter.  This will create 2 new columns, **Date created - Copy.1** and **Date created - Copy.2**.
4. Highlight the new Date column **Date created - Copy.1** and then select **Remove Rows - Remove Duplicates**.
5. At this point you should only see the latest row of data for each day.
6. Remove the 2 split columns to tidy up the dataset.